# How to put an 'if' statement in an asp Repeater ItemTemplate to determine if a DataItem list property is empty?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-lists, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a repeater that displays a two-level list:

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="MenuRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="MenuRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li <%# (Container.DataItem as LinkData).Class %>>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="MenuHyperLink" runat="server">

                </asp:HyperLink>
                    <ul>
                    <asp:Repeater DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubLinks") %>' runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li <%# (Container.DataItem as LinkData).Class %>>
                                <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></a>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</ul>
```

This works fine, but I want to make the nested lists expandable and hideable. I want to add an icon to the outer list items that shows a plus sign when "SubLinks" is not an empty list, but I'm not sure how to do that conditional statement in the repeater.

I was thinking I could do something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubLinks").Any() ?? "<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>") %>
```